# NAudio proper way to stream MediaFoundationReader

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to use NAudio to play shoutcast streams. This is doable (apparently) with a few lines of code:

```
var url = "http://dance.radiomonster.fm/320.mp3";
using(var radioStream = new MediaFoundationReader(url))
using(var wo = new WaveOutEvent())
{
    wo.Init(radioStream);
    wo.Play();
    while (wo.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Works fine for playback. However I need to take that as float samples converted to 48 KHz mono to be sent off as a bytestream elsewhere. So I do this:

```
//Convert the wave to 48 khz, mono
str1 = new WaveFormatConversionProvider(new WaveFormat(48000,1), radioStream);

//Convert the converted wave to floats
str = new Wave16ToFloatProvider(str1);
```

Under previous iterations of this I would do something like this to retrieve the data:

```
while ((readResultCount = str.Read(result, 0, result.Length)) > 0)
{
    float[] output = new float[result.Length / sizeof(float)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(result, 0, output, 0, sizeof(float) * output.Length);

    au.EnqueueEncodeVoiceData(output);
}
```

However, this results in audio output that skips worse than a CD that's been ran over.

I've tried to see if there was any way to determine if there was data enough in the buffer and avoid reading the stream if not, but there doesn't seem to be any facilities to do this.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, here's a matter of hidden knowledge.

The loop itself was being called in a timer event tick, which meant that multiple instances of the loop could (and would) get called, since the `Read` operation is apparently blocking until either the requested data is received or the stream ends for whatever reason.

Since the timer ticked indiscriminately of whether the loop had exited or not, it was running over its own toes.

I resolved this by removing the timer tick and shoving the routine into a `Task`.